# Using participial adjectives

Tags: adjectives, irregular, deverbal-adjectives, irregular-verbs

Is this grammar just for regular verbs?
Or we can use irregular verbs, too.

Comment: Yes, we can, but as modifiers (pre or post-head) of nouns, participial adjectives are actually VPs, an intermediate level between clause and verb. For example, in "a broken clock", "broken" is not an adjective but a VP.

Comment: @user17505, If you added an example of the grammatical construction that you are familar with that uses regular verbs as "participal adjectives", it might make it easier for people to write more informative answers.

Comment: I fail to see what's unclear about this question.  I don't see why a question on an English stackexchange should be closed for using specific, technical terminology, just because people who haven't studied English grammar formally might not be familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, irregular past participles have survived as adjectives long after the verb itself has become regular:

> a freshly *mown* lawn
>
> a newly *sown* field
>
> a poorly *sewn* dress
>
> *spilt* milk (only archaic in North America)

So, obviously, English doesn't mind the form at all.

Comment: Excellent answer. Shame you didn't expand. It would have been informative.